# Using CSS to generate inner and outer circles

Tags: html, css

Following the guide [here](http://davidwalsh.name/demo/css-circles.php), I've been working on generating circles using CSS. I've done the basics but am stuck trying to get one CSS-generated circle superimposed on top of another. My Fiddle is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/cvh2013/7txCN/).

I'd like to:

1. adjust the positioning of the inner circles containing the text - I'm unable to get it lined up properly on the outer circle. The idea is that each circle will be composed of an outer circle and an inner circle, and each inner circle will contain the appropriate text.
2. get the text to line up correctly so that it's centred vertically and horizontally in the inner circle
3. get all three of the circles on the same horizontal line.

Pasted below is an image of the way I'd like to get the circles to display.

Can anyone help, please?

[image: 3 circles]

HTML:

```
<div id="law-outer-circle" class="circle"><div id="law-inner-circle" class="circle">Law firms</div></div>   
<div id="industry-outer-circle" class="circle"><div id="industry-inner-circle" class="circle">Industry</div></div>
<div id="in-house-outer-circle" class="circle"><div id="in-house-inner-circle" class="circle">In-house counsel</div></div>
```

CSS:

```
.circle {
border-radius: 50%;
display: inline-block;
margin-right: 20px;

/* text styling */
font-size: 45px;
color: #FFF;
line-height: 75px;
text-align: center;
font-family: Arial;
}

#industry-inner-circle {
width: 250px;
height: 250px;
background: #DD4814;
position: absolute;
top: 24%; 
left : 24%;
display: block;
border: 2px solid #fff;
}

#industry-outer-circle {
background: #DD4814;
width: 270px;
height: 270px;
position:relative;
}

#in-house-inner-circle {
width: 250px;
height: 250px;
background: #AEA79F;
position: absolute;
top: 24%; 
left : 24%;
display: block;
border: 2px solid #fff;
}

#in-house-outer-circle {
background: #AEA79F;
width: 270px;
height: 270px;
position:relative;
}

#law-inner-circle {
width: 250px;
height: 250px;
background: #5E2750;
position: absolute;
top: 24%; 
left : 24%;
display: block;
border: 2px solid #fff;
}

#law-outer-circle {
background: #5E2750;
width: 270px;
height: 270px;
position:relative;
}
```

Comment: Like this? http://jsfiddle.net/7txCN/1/

Comment: Thank you for your input Billy, agriboz's answer works perfectly. Your comment is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do it in this way using  css `box-shadow` property.

**Html**

```
<div class="circle color-1 color1-box-shadow">
    industry
</div>
<div class="circle text color-2 color2-box-shadow">
    In-house legal counsel
</div>
<div class="circle color-3 color3-box-shadow">
    Law Firms
</div>
```

**Css**

```
.circle {
    border-radius: 50%;
    float: left;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 20px;
    /* text styling */
    font-size: 45px;
    width: 250px;
    height: 250px;
    color: #FFF;  border: 2px solid #fff;
    line-height: 250px;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: Arial;
}
.color-1 { background: #DD4814;}
.color-2 { background: #AEA79F; }
.color-3 { background: #5E2750; }
.color1-box-shadow { box-shadow: 0px 0px 1px 1px #DD4814 }
.color2-box-shadow { box-shadow: 0px 0px 1px 1px #AEA79F }
.color3-box-shadow { box-shadow: 0px 0px 1px 1px #5E2750 }
.text { line-height: 45px; padding-top: 50px; height: 200px }
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/agriboz/7txCN/3/)

Comment: That looks fantastic, thank you agriboz! Now I need to read up on box-shadow.

Comment: I am glad that i could help. You may want to check out [this](http://www.sitepoint.com/mastering-box-shadows/) to enhance about `box-shadow`.

Answer (score 1):

Give `.circle { line-height: 250px; }` (same as your inner circle height) and change inner circle `top` and `left` values to 8px
(outerCircleHeight - innerCircleHeight - bothSidesBorder / 2 = 8).

```
#industry-inner-circle {
    top: 8px;
    left : 8px;
}
```

[jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/dxRe2/)

Comment: A great answer too, and very simple. Thank you Morpheus. Neo will be happy too.